# Use execvp with Input file to a program and redirection output to a new file

Tags: c, linux, redirect, exec

I did tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322269/using-execvp-with-input-output-and-redirection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345025/how-to-save-execvp-output) but couldn't make it right (please notice the links before referring to it as a possible duplicate).

In my program I'm trying to run a program using a text file as it's input and redirecting the output of the program to a new file.

Here is my code :

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    char *args[]={"program",">","output.txt",NULL}; 
    int fd = open("/input.txt", O_RDONLY);
    dup2(fd, 0);
    execvp("program",args);

    return 0;
}
```

`program.c` is my program I'm trying to run(not my main program)
`/input.txt` is the file I want to use as an input to my `program.c`
and `output.txt` is the file I want to redirect the output of program to
I know that for redirecting my program output I should use `programname>outputfile`.

But I can't make it work, I thing maybe I'm doing something wrong with the `args array`. What is the right way to sent `input.txt` as the input for `program.c` and redirect it's output to `output.txt`? (note that my main program is  not `program.c`)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using execvp with Input,Output and redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322269/using-execvp-with-input-output-and-redirection)

Comment: @ Chris Turner I mentioned in my question i tried to use it as a reference but couldn't make my program work

Comment: But you managed to use that answer to redirect the input correctly. Redirecting the output is exactly the same

Comment: @Chris Turner how is it the same? im using int fd = open("/input.txt", O_RDONLY); for the input, but as far as I know the output should be used as programname>outputfile in the args array, and in the answer they were using the args array also for the input, which I was not managed to do

Comment: it is the same because you `open` a file and use `dup2` to replace stdout, exactly as the answer in the duplicate says and the answer below says too.

Comment: @Chris Turner  so there is no need for char *args[]={"program",">","output.txt",NULL};?

Comment: you don't need the `">","output.txt"` as it won't do what you want - as covered in the answer you've just accepted, it's a feature of the shell - the `exec` functions will just pass it as arguments to your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `programname>outputfile` is a feature of the shell. The shell opens the output file for you and duplicates the file descriptor to `1` (`stdout`).

If you don't want to run a shell you can do it like your input redirection with `open` and `dup2` before calling `exec*`. Try something like this:

```
int fdOut = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
/* don't forget to check fdOut for error indication */
int rc = dup2(fdOut, 1);
/* also check the return code for errors here */
```

Comment: Do you mean using your code after the dup2(fd, 0); and before execvp("program",args)? and make the char array just char *args[]={"program",NULL};? then how will the exec ? is it not going to make problems as to witch file is the input and which one is poor the output?

Comment: @ashly Yes, that's what I mean. The executed `program` will not know which input and output file it is connected to. It has to read its input from `stdin` (file descriptor `0`) and write its output to `stdout` (file descriptor `1`). This is the purpose of input and output redirection.

Comment: think i got he idea,thank you, one more thing,if you don't mind,whenever i run the program I can't really see the output, does using "program" and not "program.c"/"program -c " is correct? or ""/input.txt" and not "input.txt"?

Comment: @ashly What do you mean with "I can't really see the output". It doesn't appear in the output file? You can't find the output file? You don't see any output in the terminal window? Your compiled program is probably named `program` if the source code is `program.c`. `/input.txt` is a file in the root directory which is probably wrong. `input.txt` is a file in the current working directory. Please check the return code of all called functions because it will tell you if something went wrong.